# Mockito not working in spring boot service class

Tags: junit, mockito

I am trying to run the test class below with MockBean BaaisnEvcIdMSRepository. It's connecting to the real database (I am getting an exception). Please could you explain why it is not using the mock?

### Test class

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class BaaisnEvcIdMSServiceTest {

        @Autowired
        BaaisnEvcIdMSService basBaaisnEvcIdMSService;

        @MockBean
        BaaisnEvcIdMSRepository baaisnEvcIdMSRepository;


        @Test
        public void getQueryEvcidServiceTest() {

            BaaisnEvcIdRequest baaisnEvcIdRequest = new BaaisnEvcIdRequest();
            baaisnEvcIdRequest.setLata(650);
            baaisnEvcIdRequest.setProduct_type("abc");
            baaisnEvcIdRequest.setSvc_type("xyz");

            RowMapperServerResponse rowMapperServerResponse = new RowMapperServerResponse();
            rowMapperServerResponse.setId(1);
            rowMapperServerResponse.setName("sample");

            Mockito.when(baaisnEvcIdMSRepository.getQueryEvcidRepository(baaisnEvcIdRequest)).thenReturn(rowMapperServerResponse);

            assertEquals(rowMapperServerResponse, basBaaisnEvcIdMSService.getQueryEvcidService(baaisnEvcIdRequest));
        }

    }
```

### Repository

```java
    @Repository
    public class BaaisnEvcIdMSRepository {

        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Transactional
        public RowMapperServerResponse getQueryEvcidRepository(BaaisnEvcIdRequest baaisnEvcIdRequest) {
            RowMapperServerResponse rowMapperServerResponse =  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "select * from Master_Circuit WHERE master_ckt_id =  ( select max(master_ckt_id)  from master_circuit  WHERE product = ? AND id_type = ?)",
                new Object[]{baaisnEvcIdRequest.getProduct_type(),baaisnEvcIdRequest.getLata()}, new BaaisnRowMapper());
            return rowMapperServerResponse;
        }
    }
```

### exception

```
    java.sql.SQLException: com.informix.asf.IfxASFException: Attempt to connect to database server (tdclsvi1vd002_tcp_ldap) failed.
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.<init>(IfxSqliConnect.java:1691) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
```

Comment: Try using Mockito.any() in place of baaisnEvcIdRequest Mockito.when(baaisnEvcIdMSRepository.getQueryEvcidRepository(baaisnEvcIdRequest)).thenReturn(rowMapperServerResponse);

Comment: but this line gives me nullpointer exception

Comment: can you post the stacktrace of the error

Answer (score 0):

As this is unit test, you do not need spring context. So you will need something like

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BaaisnEvcIdMSServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    BaaisnEvcIdMSService basBaaisnEvcIdMSService;

    @Mock
    BaaisnEvcIdMSRepository baaisnEvcIdMSRepository;    

    @Test
    public void getQueryEvcidServiceTest() {

        BaaisnEvcIdRequest baaisnEvcIdRequest = new BaaisnEvcIdRequest();
        baaisnEvcIdRequest.setLata(650);
        baaisnEvcIdRequest.setProduct_type("abc");
        baaisnEvcIdRequest.setSvc_type("xyz");

        RowMapperServerResponse rowMapperServerResponse = new RowMapperServerResponse();
        rowMapperServerResponse.setId(1);
        rowMapperServerResponse.setName("sample");

        Mockito.when(baaisnEvcIdMSRepository.getQueryEvcidRepository(baaisnEvcIdRequest)).thenReturn(rowMapperServerResponse);

        assertEquals(rowMapperServerResponse, basBaaisnEvcIdMSService.getQueryEvcidService(baaisnEvcIdRequest));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you indeed aim for the integration test and not for the unit test (in this case, an answer provided by @Yogesh Badke is the way to go), here are some points for consideration:

1. Place the breakpoint in the test and check the type of the `baaisnEvcIdMSRepository`. If should be some sort of proxy generated by Mockito.
2. If you have a proxy indeed, check the reference to the repository in `BaaisnEvcIdMSService` instance. It also should point on proxy and not on the real class.
3. Make sure `BaaisnEvcIdRequest` implements the `equals` method otherwise Mockito might not find the expectation when the real service runs the code against the repository proxy (assuming that its a proxy indeed as I've described in "2")
4. Provide the stacktrace of how exactly it fails with exception, it might also contain some beneficial information...